# APIGEE query issue

Tags: javascript, apigee

I got an error when I try to get a Apigee collection using this code:

```
var my_pc_list = new Apigee.Collection( { "client":client, "type":"pc_pedidos", qs :{ql:"limit:50"} });
```

This is the error:

{"error":"query_parse","timestamp":1401301444160,"duration":0,"exception":"org.apache.usergrid.persistence.exceptions.QueryParseException","error_description":"The query cannot be parsed. The token 'limit' at column 0 on line 1 cannot be parsed"}

I need to increase the default limit for displaying entities, I need to show more than 10 entities.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this part:

```
qs: {ql:"limit:50"}
```

you want this:

```
qs:{limit:50}
```

There is no need to use ql (which stands for query language) because the limit statement falls outside of the ql.  For example, you might make a call like this:

```
GET /users?ql=select * where somevalue=1&limit=50
```

Notice that the limit statement is not part of the query (its not part of the ql).

If you do want to run a query in addition to the limit, like the GET /users call above, that would look like this:

```
qs:{ql:"select * where somevalue=1", limit:50}
```

Where the qs (query string) is an object made up of the key value pairs you want to go into the query string of the call that is made.